# How can I get " last inserted id to database " in Jquery Success Method?

Tags: php, jquery

Well, In my Add contact form I'm inserting data to Mysql Database using Jquery and Php. It's successfully inserted data to db. Now I'm going to redirect successful page to **index.php?cdid=$last_id**. But how can I get this **$last_id in jquery success method** ? I can only show successful message. Any Help ?

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script>
$('#addcontact').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'add_contact_process.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',      

   success: function (data) {
        $('#success').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

          if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');           

          }  
        }); 

        if( ! data.error) {     
        $('#hide').hide();              
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
           window.location.href = "../index.php"; 
           //window.location.href = "../index.php?redcdid=<?php echo $cdid; ?>"; 
           // need something like above
    },     5000); 
        }

   }
  });
});
</script>
```

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
@session_start();
require_once("../config.php");  

$company_name = ucfirst($_POST['company_name']);    
$family_name = ucfirst($_POST['family_name']);

$msg =  array();
$msg['error'] = false;

if(empty($company_name)){   
    $msg[] = "<font color='red'>Company name required. </font>";    
    $msg['error'] = true;
}                   
if(empty($family_name)){
    $msg[] = "<font color='red'>Family name required. </font>"; 
    $msg['error'] = true;                           
}                                   


if($msg['error'] === false){

    $query_2 = "INSERT INTO contact_details (cdid, family_name, given_name, work_phone, mobile_phone, email, email_private, user_id, created_date, cid) VALUES('', '$family_name', '$given_name', '$work_phone', '$mobile_phone', '$email', '$email_private', '$user_id', '$date', '$cid')";

    $query_2 =  mysql_query($query_2);
    $last_id =  mysql_insert_id();  

    if($query_2){
        $msg[] = '<font color="green"><strong>Successfully added a new contact</strong>. </font>';                  
        $another = "close";
        }
    else{
        $msg[] = '<font color="red">Sorry we can not add a new contact details. </font>';
        $msg[] .=  mysql_error();           
        $another = "close";
        }   
}       
echo  json_encode($msg);    
?>
```

Update:

*I'm using following code to Php apge:*

```
if($query_2){
$msg[] = '<font color="green"><strong>Successfully added a new contact</strong>. 
</font>';                   
$msg['last_id'] = $last_id; 
}
```

*I'm using following jquery code:*

```
if( ! data.error) {     
        $('#hide').hide();              
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
         var last_id = data.last_id;
           window.location.href = "../index.php?redcdid=last_id"; 
    },     5000); 
        }
```

Comment: Which table is you retrive last id?

Comment: just return new cdid in responce and construct new url with javascript.

Comment: In your PHP page first declear $data = array(); Then do what i wrote in my comment

Comment: Also need to modify javascript code. Can you please paste your javascript code to paste or something similar so i can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then pass a nested array on your response:

```
$data['msg'] = $msg;
$data['last_insert_id'] = $last_id;

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in JS, you need to tweak them into this:

```
success: function (response) {
    //             ^ now this will hold both the messages and the last insert id
    var data = response.msg; // separate them, messages does in data
    var last_id = response.last_insert_id; // last_id has the last insert id

},
```

Comment: How can I get the value in jquery success method ? can you show me plz ?

Comment: @Shibbir It will be available in the `data` parameter(success function).

Comment: Oh. I'm checking it now.

Comment: @Ghost It's showing success message with last inserted id. It's should be invisible to everyone.

Comment: @Shibbir what do you mean invisible? there is no such thing, even if you didn't output anything on the DOM, we could still see your requests on the `network tab` of the browser :)

Comment: @Ghost plz check my update question. Here you can see what I'm using now.

Comment: @Ghost After pressing the submit button it's showing my custom success method with last inserted id. But last inserted id shouldn't be visible. I mean it's only print my custom success method and after that it will redirect to `window.location.href = "../index.php?redcdid=last_id";`

Comment: @Shibbir then use a `setTimeout(function(/*redirect here*/), 4000);` after 4 seconds redirect the user, by the way, concatenate it: `'index.php?redcdid=' + last_id`

Comment: @Ghost It's working fine. But what I'm asking now is that After submit the button it's showing me `Successfully added a new contact. 42` this 42 is last inserted it. it's should be show only `Successfully added a new contact`.

Comment: @Shibbir don't merge `$msg['last_id']`, dont put it there! separate it in another container like that one i did in the example,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61733/discussion-between-shibbir-and-ghost).

Comment: @Shibbir or change this: `if(key !== 'error' && key !== 'last_id') {`

Comment: @Ghost Well, you see that I'm using `echo json_encode($msg);` So if I separate this `$data['last_insert_id'] = $last_id;` then can I get this last id in jquery success method ?

Comment: @Shibbir most likely its still added inside the success div is because its still not filtered, check my comment above: add `key !== 'last_id'`

Comment: @Ghost can you come on to chat conversation for couple of minutes ?

Comment: @Thanks a Lot! Great help. It's working fine :) but what this line mean `key !== 'last_id` How it's pass this validation ?

Comment: @Shibbir what happens is the last id is appended including the success message, thats why i added that validation so that it doesn't get included. glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

By using `mysql_insert_id()` you will be able to get the last id.

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Then in your PHP code do the following right after success message.

```
$data['msg'] = 'your message';                  
$data['last_id'] = $last_id;
echo json_encode($data);
```

then do the following to get the response from ajax

```
success: function (output) {
  var data = output.msg; // this is message
  var last_id = output.last_id; // this is the id
},
```

Change your javascript to below:

```
<script>
$('#addcontact').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'add_contact_process.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',      

   success: function (data) {
        $('#success').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

          if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');           

          }  
        }); 

        if( ! data.error) {     
        $('#hide').hide();              
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
           window.location.href = "../index.php"; 
           //window.location.href = "../index.php?redcdid=<?php echo $cdid; ?>"; 
           // need something like above
    },     5000); 
        }

   }
  });
});
</script>
```

TO

```
<script>
    $('#addcontact').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add_contact_process.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output) {
                //alert(output);
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(output);
               alert(result.last_id); //this will give the last id
               alert(result.msg); //this will give the message
            },
            error: function(output) {
                alert("not working whole process");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, Now everything is working fine. But when I press the submit button it's showing me my custom success message with last inserted id. It's should be only show my custom success message. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last insert id

```
mysql_insert_id()....
```

bt  instead of this , you should to use

pdo...that's very simple and good...

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

in pdo u can execute your query by just..

create instance of pdo in your config file..

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

you can fetch data by ...

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour);
$sth->execute();

you can get last insert id by 

 $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

pdo is simple and secure.....