# Ajax, retrieving ID of insert from within function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use Ajax to insert form data into the database and return the ID of that insertion.

It currently works as far as inserting (I can see it in the database) but I'm using `alert` to test that it's getting the ID of the insert and it simply says undefined.

Is there something I'm doing wrong to retrieve the ID?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitForm").click(function(){

      var string = $('#pageForm').serialize();

      // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addPage.php",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
          alert(result.id);//this will alert you the last_id

        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

addPage.php

```
$title = $_POST['addTitle'];
$page_type = $_POST['pageType'];
$display_id = $_POST['displayId'];
$duration = $_POST['durationSet'];

$addpage = "
    INSERT INTO pages (title, page_type_id, display_id, duration)
    VALUES ('$title','$page_type','$display_id','$duration');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addpage) === TRUE) {
$last_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
echo json_encode(['id'=>$last_id]);
echo "New record created successfully" . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addpage . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

Comment: can you add the code of addPage.php?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's in there now

Comment: You are not returning any inserted data, how you will get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return last inserted data id

```
$title = $_POST['addTitle'];
$page_type = $_POST['pageType'];
$display_id = $_POST['displayId'];
$duration = $_POST['durationSet'];

$addpage = "
    INSERT INTO pages (title, page_type_id, display_id, duration)
    VALUES ('$title','$page_type','$display_id','$duration');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addpage) === TRUE) {
$last_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
$data = json_encode(['id'=>$last_id]);
echo "New record created successfully" . $data ;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addpage . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought I was defining it in the function I didn't realize I had to return it there but that makes perfect sense

Comment: But now that I added this, how can I return the ID in JSON within my ajax call

Comment: See my updated code, but my ajax alert still returns undefined

Comment: the `result` variable only contains the content that addPage returned, so you need to have only 1 echo if you want to be able to use it. You can put your message in an array if you still want to give the status

Comment: @LioraHaydont what do you mean exactly? I tried using json_encode, I just want to return the inserted ID in JSON on my initial page that contains the ajax so that I can use the id in other ajax insert calls

Comment: "*you need to have only 1 echo if you want to be able to use json_encode*"

Comment: @MohammadRaheem It still says undefined for some reason but it's starting to make more sense now

Comment: @LioraHaydont I've successfully made the changes for json_encode in my php, but even using console.log to parse the json in my JS it shows undefined in the console

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Please first search before ask a question

```html
if ($mysqlConn->query($addpage) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully" . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addpage . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

Comment: Even with doing this, how do I include it back in my ajax though? Say I want to have it returned in json

Comment: you need to return last id. Now test it with this one.

Comment: Ok I tried this without changing the ajax, the alert still says undefined though

Comment: please first read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988753/how-can-i-get-last-inserted-id-to-database-in-jquery-success-method

Comment: If you see in my updated code, I did insert a line for using json_encode. but I'm still missing the passing of the last id